# Spark window function filtering rows which doesn't match requirement

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

what I wish to do is to get the max of two row's window. and delete last rows because it only calculate one row.

for example, the below is source data

| seconds | value |
| --- | --- |
| 225 | 1.5 |
| 245 | 0.5 |
| 300 | 2.4 |
| 319 | 1.2 |
| 320 | 4.6 |

and the table below is what I wanted. it drop 320 seconds because it's the latest one and it's only has its own.

| seconds | max |
| --- | --- |
| 225 | 1.5 |
| 245 | 2.4 |
| 300 | 2.4 |
| 319 | 4.6 |

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a row number based on descending seconds, and remove the last row using a filter:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'max',
    F.max('value').over(Window.orderBy('seconds').rowsBetween(0, 1))
).withColumn(
    'rn',
    F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.desc('seconds')))
).filter('rn != 1').drop('rn', 'value')

df2.show()
+-------+---+
|seconds|max|
+-------+---+
|    319|4.6|
|    300|2.4|
|    245|2.4|
|    225|1.5|
+-------+---+
```